# How can I disable the arrows on a FlipView?

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a FlipView, which is working great, but I'd like to disable the < and > arrows that fade in while scrolling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that would break the scenario for keyboard/mouse users, no?

You could remove the buttons from the control template if you really need to.

Comment: How can I access to the control template of the flipview?

Comment: Right-click the FlipView in the designer view, select Edit Template/Edit Current and voilà! The template gets extracted to your XAML file.

Comment: Worked for me in Blend. And then I just changed the width of PreviousButtonHorizontal, NextButtonHorizontal, PreviousButtonVertical, and NextButtonVertical all to 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are 2 options.**

**Option 1.** In `FlipView.Loaded` event dynamically remove the arrow buttons.

```
private void flipView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(flipView, 0);
    for (int i = grid.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (grid.Children[i] is Button)
            grid.Children.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

**Option 2.** Edit the template of the `FlipView` control (as Filip Skakun said in his answer).

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39820611/5292302) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)