# how to disable default (next/prev) buttons of flip in winrt xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

i am working on winrt flipview.
in this i **want to disable its default next and prev buttons of FlipView**. but the fliping can be done by another buttons. can any one please tell me how to disable default(next/prev) buttons in winrt xaml

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906073/how-can-i-disable-the-arrows-on-a-flipview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to re-template the control and remove those elements.

Comment: how to do this is there any examples

Comment: 1. Add a FlipView to your app.
2. Open app in Blend.
3. Right-Click the FlipView in Blend and select Edit Template > Edit a Copy. 4. Find the next/prev buttons and disable or remove them.

Comment: 'You would need to re-template the control and remove those elements.' well thats really helpful isn't it. zero instructions on how we go about this?

Comment: Here you can find how to edit template http://irisclasson.com/2012/07/22/example-winrtmetro-app-how-to-edit-default-template-in-visual-studio-2012-and-blend/

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 options.**

**Option 1.** In `FlipView.Loaded` event dynamically remove the arrow buttons.

```
private void flipView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(flipView, 0);
    for (int i = grid.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (grid.Children[i] is Button)
            grid.Children.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

**Option 2.** Retemplate the `FlipView` control (as Tim Heuer stated in his answer).